# System.Windows.Media in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Recently I wrote a WPF program for detecting faces in the pictures. This program uses one of the ProjectOxford's APIs that is known as FaceAPI.
Then I got an idea to port my application from WPF to UWP (Universal Windows Platform). But, during the development I faced up the problem with System.Windows.Media namespace. In my UWP application I just do not have such namespace, consequently I can not get access to all included classes, such that DrawingVisual, DrawingContext etc.

Here is problematic code block from WPF which need to be ported to UWP:

```
if (faceRects.Length > 0)
{
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawindContext = visual.RenderOpen();

    drawindContext.drawimage(bitmapImage,
        new Rect(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height));

    double dpi = bitmapImage.DpiX;
    double resizefactor = 96 / dpi;

    foreach (var facerect in faceRects)
    {
        drawindContext.drawrectangle(
            Brushes.transparent,
            new Pen(Brushes.red, 2),
            new Rect(
                faceRect.Left * resizefactor,
                faceRect.Top * resizefactor,
                faceRect.Width * resizefactor,
                faceRect.Height * resizefactor
            )
        );
    }

    drawindcontext.close();

    rendertargetbitmap facewithrectbitmap = new rendertargetbitmap(
        (int)(bitmapsource.pixelwidth * resizefactor),
        (int)(bitmapsource.pixelheight * resizefactor),
        96,
        96,
        pixelformats.pbgra32);

    facewithrectbitmap.render(visual);

    facephoto.source = facewithrectbitmap;
}
```

Any ideas how to replace that?

Comment: Should you be using [Windows.Media](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/windows/apps/windows.media.aspx) instead?  Also, _[check out this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)_

Comment: The corresponding namespace in Windows Runtime is `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media`. However, there is nothing like DrawingVisual and DrawingContext in it. These classes aren't available in Window Runtime. Take a look at the Windows Runtime API documentation of [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx).

Comment: Hey @KonstantinChsherbakov, I seem to have the exact same problem. What API did you end up using if I might ask?

Comment: @kskyriacou Same here, what did you do eventually? Could you post solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP uses a new set of namespaces -- the majority of these prefixed with Windows.* which is in contrast to the System.* prefix for WPF, although there are System.* namespaces used both by UWP and WPF. Here is a  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) for the new namespaces. You may also like to read the [Guide to Universal Windows Platform apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) for a better grasp of UWP basics.

As shown in the comment section, what you need is a namespace that starts with Windows.* and the links provided should put you right.